# Valgrind shows possibly lost memory

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, malloc, valgrind

Essentially, I'm trying to implement a singly linked list in C, and I'm using valgrind to check for any memory leaks. Valgrind shows a memory leak as "possibly lost" but I've freed every malloc on the heap and I'm not sure where it's occurring.

Here's the a link to the image of my memory error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG5pm.jpg

And Here is my code, with the output being shown in the valgrind image.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* defines node object */
struct node
{
    /* node holds data */
    long data;

    /* next pointer */
    struct node *next;
};


struct node * buildList (void);
long getElement (struct node *, int index);
int lenList(struct node *Head);
void insertList(struct node **Head);
void delete_List (struct node **Head);

/* builds a list of four nodes */
struct node * buildList (void)
{
    struct node * head = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node * second = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node * third = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node * fourth = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head ->data = 1;
    head ->next = second;
    second ->data = 2;
    second ->next = third;
    third ->data = 3;
    third ->next = fourth;
    fourth ->data = 4;
    fourth ->next = NULL;

    /* returns pointer to first node*/
    return head;
}

/* gets value at list index */
long getElement(struct node *Head, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<index; i++)
    {
        Head = Head -> next;
    }
    return Head -> data;
}

/* gets length of list */
int lenList(struct node *Head)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (Head != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        Head = Head->next;
    }
    return counter;
}

/* inserts node at beginning of list, resets head pointer to new node */
void insertList(struct node **Head)
{
    struct node *newnode = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = 0;
    newnode->next = *Head;

    /* head pointer now points to first node */
    *Head = newnode;
}

/* deletes and deallocates list memory */
void delete_List (struct node **Head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *current = *Head;
    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        temp = current;
        current = current -> next;
        free(temp);
    }

    /* mark list as empty */
    *Head = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node * headpointer = buildList();
    printf("Initial length of list is: %d\n", lenList(headpointer));
    insertList(&headpointer);
    printf("After inserting node, list length is: %d\n", lenList(headpointer));
    printf("The data at index 1 is: %ld\n", getElement(headpointer, 1));
    delete_List(&headpointer);
    printf("Headpointer should now be equal to null: %x\n", headpointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post text, don't link images...

Comment: Text is hard to format.

Comment: I'm not getting you. Copy paste it. Select it and press ctrl+k. That's it.

Comment: On Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit system. Using valgrind-3.11.0, (valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./a.out) does not show any mem leaks.

Comment: Does on Mac OSx, wonder why there's a discrepancy.

Comment: How you run your program under valgrind ..can you paste your command?

Comment: valgrind --leak-check=yes ./LinkedList

Comment: This seems similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848754/valgrind-memory-leak-or-no/25300686#25300686

Comment: Also, please post any program outputs, etc, into Stackoverflow, not hosted offsite.

Comment: I get no leaks in valgrind. But you probably should change the final `printf()` to: `printf("Headpointer should now be equal to null: %p\n", (void *)headpointer);`