# Why doesn't valgrind detect this possible memory leak due to realloc?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I can't understand why valgrind (version 3.14) doesn't detect a possible memory leak in this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  p = realloc(p, 2 * sizeof(int));

  free(p);

  return 0;
}
```

The C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999, page 314) says this about `realloc`:

> If memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged. [...]
>   The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same
>   value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.

So it may occur that `p` is `NULL` but the memory cell previously allocated with `malloc` is still there, shouldn't this be a possible memory leak?

If I compile the program with `gcc -std=c99` and I execute valgrind with `--tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes` it gives the following message:

```
==313618== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==313618== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==313618== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==313618== Command: ./a.out
==313618== 
==313618== 
==313618== HEAP SUMMARY:
==313618==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==313618==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 12 bytes allocated
==313618== 
==313618== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==313618== 
==313618== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==313618== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: This is a good reason why you should assign the return value from `realloc` to a temporary variable to test before you overwrite the original pointer. Then if `NULL` was returned your recovery action can `free` the original pointer, instead of having lost it.

Comment: More on what valgrind means by "possible" in this context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771610/what-does-possible-lost-means-in-valgrind

Comment: @WeatherVane I knew that this use of realloc is wrong, the problem was why valgrind didn't detect it.

Comment: @JETM This is really useful, however "possible" is a misleading name, as well as the message "no leaks are possible"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Valgrind does not analyze your code; it analyzes the actions taken by your code.

In this particular run `realloc` did not fail, so there was no memory leak, so valgrind had nothing to report:

> All heap blocks were freed

And that's all valgrind knows.

To detect the problem in your code you need a static code analysis tool.

Comment: Yes, as you stated in answer by using `cppcheck` a static C/C++ code analyzer we can detect these problem.

Comment: On GNU/Linux `sudo apt install cppcheck` and `cppcheck source.c` produce:  `9]: (error) Common realloc mistake: 'p' nulled but not freed upon failure`

Comment: Correct the original code: `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
 int *tmp = NULL;
 
    tmp = realloc(p, 2 * sizeof(int));
 if (tmp){
   p=tmp;
   free(tmp);
   tmp=NULL;
 }else{
  printf("error\n");
  tmp=NULL;
 }
     free(p);`

Comment: @EsmaeelE Thank you, I tried using cppcheck and it correctly warns me.