# Why does valgrind report that glibc tsearch() randomly leaks memory?

Tags: c, valgrind, glibc

I'm using the glibc [`tsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tsearch.html) API family to store dynamically allocated data blocks in an example program.

I am finding that when I use `tsearch()` to add several `malloc()`ed blocks to a tree, then valgrind reports some of those blocks as "possibly lost".  While "possibly lost" is not quite the same as "definitely lost", the [previous SO advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537713/valgrind-can-possibly-lost-be-treated-as-definitely-lost) is generally to investigate what is causing these.

My example program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <search.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct data {
    int id;
    char *str;
};

static int
compare (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct data *data_a = a, *data_b = b;

    if (data_a->id < data_b->id) {
        return -1;
    } else if (data_a->id > data_b->id) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    void *tree = NULL;
    struct data *d1, *d2, *d3, *d4;

    d1 = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    d1->id = 10;
    d1->str = "Hello";
    tsearch(d1, &tree, compare);

    d2 = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    d2->id = 30;
    d2->str = "Goodbye";
    tsearch(d2, &tree, compare);

    d3 = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    d3->id = 20;
    d3->str = "Thanks";
    tsearch(d3, &tree, compare);

    d4 = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    d4->id = 40;
    d4->str = "OK";
    tsearch(d4, &tree, compare);

    raise(SIGINT);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I'm calling `raise(SIGINT)` at the end of `main()` so that valgrind is still able to analyse allocated blocks before they are implicitly `free()`d.

I am compiling and running under `valgrind` as follows:

```
$ gcc ts.c -o ts
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./ts
==2091== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2091== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2091== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2091== Command: ./ts
==2091== 
==2091== 
==2091== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==2091==    at 0x4E7AE97: raise (raise.c:51)
==2091==    by 0x1088CE: main (in /home/ubuntu/ts)
==2091== 
==2091== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2091==     in use at exit: 160 bytes in 8 blocks
==2091==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 0 frees, 160 bytes allocated
==2091== 
==2091== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 8 of 8
==2091==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2091==    by 0x4F59483: tsearch (tsearch.c:338)
==2091==    by 0x108801: main (in /home/ubuntu/ts)
==2091== 
==2091== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2091==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2091==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2091==      possibly lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==2091==    still reachable: 136 bytes in 7 blocks
==2091==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2091== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==2091== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==2091== 
==2091== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2091== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

$
```

Valgrind is reporting that one 24 byte block is lost.  If I move the `raise(SIGINT)` ahead of the `d4` allocation and tree add, then no blocks are reported lost.

Why is one block lost when adding 4 blocks, even when none are lost when adding 3 blocks?

Comment: some of the libc function do not bother freeing memory to save performance. This means take care of keeping small amounts they use a bay. valgrind reports this memory as leaked, but it gets returned at the app exit.

Comment: @Serge *some of the libc function do not bother freeing memory to save performance* <sup>citation needed</sup>.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the glibc `tsearch()` implementation is a bit naughty and can twiddle low-order bits in pointers to blocks that it has stored in a binary-search tree.  It uses low-order bits in pointers to store flags:
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/misc/tsearch.c.html#341

In particular, the implementation uses these macros to set or clear the low-order pointer bit to mark a block as red or black respectively:

```
#define SETRED(N) (N)->left_node |= ((uintptr_t) 0x1)
#define SETBLACK(N) (N)->left_node &= ~((uintptr_t) 0x1)
```

The pointers are effectively incremented which makes valgrind think these valid pointers (which are stored in a `tsearch()` tree) have been [overwritten and therefore possibly lost](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost).  But these are not lost blocks - They are successfully stored in the binary-search tree, modulo the low-order bit.  `tsearch()` will do the necessary masking of these bits when accessing the tree.  tsearch() can do this because `malloc()`ed blocks are generally aligned to at least even addresses.

Only the blocks that are marked as "red" nodes in the binary tree have this bit set, so the pattern of which are "possibly lost" or not is entirely dependent on how the implementation categorises blocks as "red" or "black" during add, delete and rebalance operations.

So `tsearch()`s bit-twiddling makes valgrind incorrectly think these blocks are lost.  In this case, valgrind is reporting false positives.

Comment: odd, but I don't agree about your wording here valgrind clearly say "possibly lost" so it's just possible, it never say it was certain, so valgrind is not incorrect here.

Comment: @Stargateur Fair enough, though [earlier SO advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537713/valgrind-can-possibly-lost-be-treated-as-definitely-lost) recommends that "possibly-lost" should generally be treated as "lost".

Comment: Well, the question you link quote valgrind doc, "Possibly lost, or “dubious”", this is clearly the case, this implementation do something really unsafe and totally implemented behavior. You are not suppose to play with pointer like that but they can because they are the implementation (glibc). Still, valgrind is right about this pointer no longer exist, the pointer have "moved" a little so valgrind report possibly because a pointer still refer to something close to the original address. Again this is the case so I don't see why valgrind should be considered buged here.

Comment: @Stargateur If you find any implications in this post that this is a valgrind bug, then that was not my intention.

Comment: "Possibly lost" is not "lost". In C, you can perform any invertible transformation you like on the representation of a pointer, even encrypting it and uploading it to the cloud and later downloading and decrypting it, without "losing" the object pointed to. The only hack here is the (implementation-specific) knowledge that `|1` is invertible on pointers returned by `malloc`.